# Are there stories that reference Chaos?

Tags: greek

Are there any other instances, besides the initial moment of the beginning, where Chaos is referenced in ancient Greek mythology?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "besides the initial moment of the beginning"? There are several references to Chaos in Greek mythology, but I'm not entirely sure any of them is what you are looking for. You may find most of these references on theoi.com: https://www.theoi.com/Protogenos/Khaos.html